# Select element based on applied property

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I love the "after" (`+`) selector, it's good to style things after specific elements.
Such as:

```
.title+div {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

would make the background color of the div following the element with `.title` class, yellow.

However, I need a more dynamic way of selecting things.

How would you express this in css?:

"Make the background color of the `visibility:visible` element, yellow"

Any direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can't select non-inline properties in CSS, so something like `div[visibility:visible]` wouldn't work unless you explicitly stated the property inside the style attribute for the element.

The best way to select an element like this is to select the *class* with the styles applied to it (if there is one).

```
.title + .visible {
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

If this isn't the case, you should almost always use JavaScript.

Comment: Hm, that's what I was afraid of. Anyway, thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Well as you know there isn't only one type of selector in CSS. In the link below you can find more complex selector such as Attribute Selector:

```css
div[target]{background-color:yellow}
.firstgroup
{
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    background-color:lightblue; 
    margin:10px;
}
.secondgroup
{
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    background-color:lightpink; 
    margin:10px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="firstgroup" target="a"></div>

<div class="firstgroup"></div>

<div class="secondgroup" target="ab"></div>

<div class="firstgroup"></div>

<div class="secondgroup"></div>
```

Refrence :[Complex Selectors](http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/complex-selectors/)

Comment: Please include a summary of what the article says in your answer so that your answer can be useful when the site goes down

Comment: Thanks for adding to your answer! But what does this have to do with the question being asked?

Comment: While the link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the linked page here and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Well as far as I understood we want to select only one specific group of objects. We can use either one of the selectors. I think the Attribute selector is probably the best answer. But since I don't know exactly what position the objects hold towards each other in this specific case, I just decided to provide a few examples. But the attribute selector sounds about right. [link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_attribute) @ZachSaucier

Comment: I appreciate your consideration. I am new to this site and I am still learning the best way to answer the questions. I will go for another edit now. @ZachSaucier

Comment: This is a much better answer :) The only improvement is that you should probably relate the attribute selector to the situation in the question - selecting an applied property

Comment: @ZachSaucier what do you think?

Answer (score 1):

This is *potentially* possible, albeit it's very, *very* fragile and has some requirements.

First, the `visibility:visible` must appear in the element's inline `style` attribute, like so:

```
<span style="visibility:visible">element text</span>
```

Second you must know the *exact* string, if a space is added you'll need to either change selector or account for both/all possibilities.

So, with those provisos, you can implement this selection as follows:

```css
[style*="visibility:visible"] {
  background-color: yellow;
}

[style*="visibility: visible"] {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<span style="visibility:visible">element text</span>
<span style="visibility: visible">element text</span>
```

Now, given those requirements, it's usually far easier to just use JavaScript (or one of its libraries, if you must):

```js
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('span'), function (el, index) {
  if (el.offsetHeight) {
    el.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
    el.textContent = el.textContent + ' (' + index + ')';
  }
})
```

```css
span {
  visibility: visible;
}

.jsAddedClass {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#exception {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<span>element text</span>
<span>element text</span>
<span id="exception"></span>
```

References:

- CSS:

  - [Substring matching (`[attribute*="value"]`) attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-substrings).
- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [`HTMLElement.offsetHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.offsetHeight).